# Filter $scope based on search field and value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I'm looking to filter an ng-repeat with a search field () and a set value. but the methods I see online are not working. Here is my example:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="List Filter... " ng-model="search" />

<tr ng-repeat="row in orgs | filter:{IsActive:false, search} | orderBy:['NetworkOrgFullName']">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You putted filter in wrong way. You should apply filter by `search` `ng-model` before applying `{IsActive: false}` filter.

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in orgs | filter: search | filter:{IsActive:false} | orderBy:['NetworkOrgFullName']">
```

Comment: @crowsfeet Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Anything wrong with multiple filters:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in orgs | filter: search | filter:{IsActive:false, SpecialID:PassedID} | orderBy:['NetworkOrgFullName']">
```